# Inherit attributes and lifecycle functions of Sails.js models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I want to create a custom set of attributes and lifecycle methods that are shared between all my Sails.js models.

Sails.js automatically creates and registers the model objects by calling the `Waterline.Collection.extend()` method and providing the model definition found inside the `/api/models` directory.

What would be the best way to extend my model definition from a parent? I already tried using `_.extend(sails.config.model.parentModel, childModel)` but sadly the `sails` object is not exposed globally (since this is done after loading the orm hook). I could also simply `require()` the base model in all my models and extend it.

What would be a clean approach that goes well with Sails?

Comment: Just found out that there is `sails.config.model` that is merged with each model while normalizing. Does it make sense to use this as a base model when implementing lifecycle functions? My base model defines the  `toJSON()` method. What should I do when my child models need to override this as well?

Comment: Currently I'm keeping an eye on keeping the parents `toJSON()` behavior intact when overriding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `config/models.js` to provide global defaults for models is perfectly valid. Concerning overriding instance and class methods there is nothing fancy to watch out for according to my tests. Defining a property / method present in `sails.config.models` in a model definition will override it for this model, leaving it undefined won't.

**Definitions**:

```
// config/models.js
module.exports.models = {
  attributes: {
    // base model instanceMethod
    toJSON: function() {
      console.log('base.toJSON');
      return this.toObject();
    }
  },

  // base model classMethod
  test: function() {
    console.log('base.test');
  }
};


// api/models/first.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {

  },

  // Overriding classMethods and lifecycle callbacks
  test: function() {
    console.log('first.test');
  }
};

// api/models/second.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    // Overriding instance methods and attributes
    toJSON: function() {
      console.log('second.toJSON');
      return this.toObject();
    }
  },
}
```

**Tests**

```
> sails.models.first.test();
>'first.test' // sails.config.models.test overridden

> sails.models.first.findOne(1).exec(err,res){ res.toJSON();  });
> 'base.toJSON' // sails.config.models.attributes.toJSON not overridden

> sails.models.second.test();
> 'base.test'; // sails.config.models.test not overridden

> sails.models.second.findOne(1).exec(err,res) { res.toJSON(); });
> 'second.toJSON' // sails.config.models.attributes.toJSON overridden
```

Comment: Is it possible to call the parent method? Calling `sails.models.toJSON()` like the following will get "no method" error although I can see the function listed (through `console.log`). 

    // api/models/second.js
    module.exports = {
      attributes: {
        // Overriding instance methods and attributes
        toJSON: function() {
          var somethingElse = sails.models.toJSON();
          // do other stuff..
          return somethingElse;
        }
      },
    }