# Upsert in waterline ORM (Sails.js)

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am looking for a way to perform MongoDB's upsert operation in waterline. One way is to use the native method.

```
Model.native(function (err, Collection){
    Collection.update({"key": "val"}, {"$set": {"x": "val"}}, {"upsert": true}, function (err, updated){
        // do something
    })
})
```

But if I don't want to use native, I could see on similar function `findOrCreate`, which creates a new entry if the item does not exist. However, I could not find a way to update the item if it exists. Is that possible or one has to use the native method only for that ?

**Note**: I am using Sails 0.11

Answer (score 4):

As of now (v0.10.26) there is no way of doing a Mongo-style upsert besides the ones you've mentioned. This keeps coming up every [once in a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936910/sails-js-model-insert-or-update-records) but I couldn't find an [issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues) addressing it directly, so maybe you could [raise](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/new) one.

**Update**
[This issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/790) talks about `updateOrCreate` and the linked threads suggest this might be added soon. I was looking into the Sails issues initially so no wonder I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In Sails 1.0 you can also perform native queries this way:

```
var db = YourCollection.getDatastore().manager;
var rawYourCollection = db.collection(YourCollection.tableName);
let dbRes = await rawYourCollection.updateOne(
  { findParams },
  { $set: { setParams } },
  { upsert: true }
);
```