# How to extend waterline with custom query methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I want to create and use some custom query methods for waterline.

For example method `makeItAwesome`:

```
Article.makeItAwesome({
    id: 42
}).exec(function(err, awesomeArticle) {
    /* ... */
});
```

Of course I can add this `makeItAwesome` to model's static methods but what if I want common stuff reusable for other models. Does sails.js or waterline by itself have built-in ways of doing it or I should do it by myself?

If not where is the best way to keep this stuff? Must it be a separate module to require in each model or I can somewhere extend each model prototype once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put methods you want on every model in a common js file and use lodash to extend your models with these defaults. Or simply reference the imported actions when defining your model.

module.exports = _.extends(makeItAwsomeDefinition, { thisModelDefinition })

-- OR --

You can add default methods to your config/models.js file

-- OR --

If your just using blueprints, you can create custom actions and put them in api/blueprints

-- OR --

A simpler method I might use, is to create a service and put my custom methods in there. ModelMethodsService.makeItAwsome('MODELNAME',{structOfQueryParams})

**References**

- [Model/Controller prototype inheritence](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/GTGoOGHAEvE)
- [Inherit attributes and lifecycle functions of Sails.js models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996366/inherit-attributes-and-lifecycle-functions-of-sails-js-models)
- [Custom blueprint actions](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api?q=overriding-blueprints)
- [Creating Services](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Services)

Comment: In Waterline 0.13 (Sails v1.0) instance methods on models have been removed.